# HTTP call from C++ using CPR?

Tags: c++, http, c++11, post

I would to like to make a POST request in cpp using [CPR Github Library](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr)

Equivalent `curl` request is given below.

```
echo '{"fund_name": "UTI Dual Advantage Fixed Term Fund Series I-IV (1099 Days) - Direct Plan - Dividend Option","from_date":"2015-01-15","to_date": "2016-12-15"}' | curl -d @- http://<ip>:<port>/api/v1/es/search
```

When i try to call using this code, always receive `500`.

```
auto r1 = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{"http://<ip>:<port>/api/v1/es/search"},
                           cpr::Payload{{"fund_name", fundName},
                                         {"from_date", startDate},
                                         {"to_date", endDate}}
        );
```

I think, i am faling to convert the `json` properly. Any suggestion.

And i am able to make get request using cpr.

```
auto r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{"https://api.github.com/repos/whoshuu/cpr/contributors"},
                      cpr::Authentication{"user", "pass"},
                      cpr::Parameters{{"anon", "true"}, {"key", "value"}});
    r.status_code;                  // 200
    r.header["content-type"];       // application/json; charset=utf-8
    r.text;                         // JSON text string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to pass the `json` object into body.

```
        Json my_json = Json::object {
                {"fund_name", fundName},
                {"from_date", startDate},
                {"to_date", endDate}
        };
        auto r1 = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{"http://<ip>:<port>/api/v1/es/search"},
                            cpr::Body{my_json.dump()}
        );
```

`cpr::Payloads{}`,`cpr::Parameters{}` passes the arguments in `url` params.